# Not getting a JSON response from youtube data api

Tags: java

This is the URL I am using to request a particular youtube channel data from my Android Studio project

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCX4kkW2kc-x_3EbbkxhZZLw&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

I am getting a 400 error response code

Comment: And what is the message with it ? This is usually helpful PS: I hope you have set YOUR API KEY value

Comment: Please provide the code with which you are building/sending the request.

Comment: The easiest in this case is too look on the [related doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors)

Comment: 01-02 13:17:54.229 16527-16560/com.example.android.video E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x629bbaf0 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x612f7940 arg=0x0
01-02 13:17:54.230 16527-16560/com.example.android.video E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x629bbaf0 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA

Comment: The third error is error code 400.May be i am missing something in the request.But I can't figure out what it is.